# Getting the facebook feed

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

Different question, so different thread ;)

How can I get the facebook feed for a user? If I access /me/feed I only seem to get feed items from me and not from all the friends who posted, or the feed from their wall for that matter. I'm trying to get everything I can normally see on my wall - only further back.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home
```

This gives you the news feed as you see to want

If you want the feed from their wall then use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/THEIR_USERID/feed
```

Though they must have authenticated your application to get this